# Displaying a video using laravel 5.2

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5

I am working on Laravel 5.2. I have to display a video on my view page.I am able to store the video in my database table but, not able to fetch it and display it.I have the column in my table having the filepath of the videos which i am using to fetch it from the database.

My Controller:

```
   public function talent(Request $request){
   $user=new Talent(); 
   $this->validate($request, [

     'video'=>'required',
   ]);
   $video=$request->file('video');


   $filename=time().'.'. $video->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $pathVideo = public_path('uploads/video/' . $filename);
   Input::file('video')->move('uploads/video/', $pathVideo);
   $user->file_path=$pathVideo;


   $user->video=$filename;

   $user->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
   $user->save();

    return redirect()->back();

    }

   public function talentpool($id){
   $user=User::findorFail($id);
   $talents=Talent::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
   return view('talentpool',['user'=>$user,'talents'=>$talents]);
    }
```

My View:

```
   @foreach($talents as $talent)
   <video width="616" src="{{ $talent->file_path }}" controls></video>
   @endforeach
```

Comment: Try inspecting HTML source to check what are you getting in video src attribute? Also double check you are returning to correct view in talentpool function.

Comment: get the value from src="", paste into browser url bar and hit enter.

Comment: it is showing blank in the video src attribute while inspecting the element

Comment: sorry @ jakub wrona

Comment: Try dd($talents) in your view, to check if data is there or not.

Comment: yeah, by using dd, i am able to get the filepath

Comment: but when i am using it in my view to display the video, i am getting nothing there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php.ini files contains some limits that might affect this. Try changing these to high enough values:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
memory_limit = 32M
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($talents as $talent)
   <video width="320" height="240" controls>
       <source src="{{ $talent->file_path }}" type="video/mp4">
       <source src="{{ $talent->file_path }}" type="video/ogg">
       Your browser does not support the video tag.
   </video>
@endforeach
```

If your path is not absolute use asset .

Comment: i tried it, but it didn,t work. i got this code from the google through stack overflow but, it still didn't work.

Comment: may be, my browser does not support the video tag??

Comment: Give Me An Screen Shot With Inspect Element .